# Using "if statements" to add classes in Twig

Tags: 8, theming

I'm attempting to use an if statement to determine the value of a field and print a class based on that value. I'm not getting any errors, but the addClass is not working. No classes are being added. I'm assuming it's a simple syntax error. I'm a designer first, and I'm new to Twig templating. Thank you in advance!

```
{% for key, item in content.field_stat_value if key|first != '#' %}
    <div class="stat-column">
        <div 
        {% if content.field_special_character[key] == '%' %}
          {{ attributes.addClass('percent') }}
        {% elseif content.field_special_character[key] == '$' %}
          {{ attributes.addClass('dollar') }}
        {% endif %}
        class="stat counter" data-count="{{ content.field_stat_value[key] }}">0</div>
        <div class="title">{{ content.field_stat_title[key] }}</div>
        <div>{{content.field_special_character[key]}}</div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: IMO this is so much easier to do in preprocess instead of add a lot of conditional logic to twig files trying to read from render arrays.

Comment: @Kevin That sounds great, but I have very limited experience with writing preprocess statements. Any recommendations on how to do so, or good places to learn?

Comment: Any luck on this? Just looking at the code above, `attributes.addClass('percent')` is correct. So either your template isn't loading, or those `if` checks are evaluating to null, or at least not `%/$`. Try adding the classes without the `if` check. If that prints the class at least you know to look at your `{% if content.field_special_character[key] == '%' %}` statements.

Comment: @Prestosaurus I actually found an easier way to accomplish what I needed. There was no logic needed! I just injected the raw field value as the class value.

Answer (score 1):

1) Install and enable the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

2) Add your **/sites/development.services.yml**:

```
# Local development services.
#
# Place this file in the /sites/ directory.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    # Twig debugging:
    #
    # When debugging is enabled:
    # - The markup of each Twig template is surrounded by HTML comments that
    #   contain theming information, such as template file name suggestions.
    # - Note that this debugging markup will cause automated tests that directly
    #   check rendered HTML to fail. When running automated tests, 'debug'
    #   should be set to FALSE.
    # - The dump() function can be used in Twig templates to output information
    #   about template variables.
    # - Twig templates are automatically recompiled whenever the source code
    #   changes (see auto_reload below).
    #
    # For more information about debugging Twig templates, see
    # https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392.
    #
    # Not recommended in production environments
    # @default false
    debug: true
    # Twig auto-reload:
    #
    # Automatically recompile Twig templates whenever the source code changes.
    # If you don't provide a value for auto_reload, it will be determined
    # based on the value of debug.
    #
    # Not recommended in production environments
    # @default null
    auto_reload: auto_reload
    # Twig cache:
    #
    # By default, Twig templates will be compiled and stored in the filesystem
    # to increase performance. Disabling the Twig cache will recompile the
    # templates from source each time they are used. In most cases the
    # auto_reload setting above should be enabled rather than disabling the
    # Twig cache.
    #
    # Not recommended in production environments
    # @default true
    cache: false
```

3) Add your **/sites/default/settings.local.php**:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Local development override configuration feature.
 *
 * Place this file in the /sites/default/ directory next to settings.php.
 * This will include the development.services.yml file for twig debug use.
 *
 */
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, TRUE);
\Drupal\Component\Assertion\Handle::register();

$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;

$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;
$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = TRUE;
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

4) Update your **/sites/default/settings.php**:

(uncomment this section)

```
# if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
#   include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
# }
```

This will allow you to add `{{ dump(content.field_name | keys) }}` to your template file so you can see just what keys you need to access the correct values.

Try:

```
{% for key, item in content.field_stat_value %}
  <pre>
    {{ dump(content.field_special_character | keys) }}
  </pre>
{% endfor %}
```

Then just add what you need to follow:

```
{% for key, item in content.field_stat_value %}
  <pre>
    {{ dump(content.field_special_character.mynextkey.0.whatever | keys) }}
  </pre>
{% endfor %}
```

I add this answer as being able to print out values will help a designer best. Plus, if your class is not printing, I just think `content.field_special_character[key]` is not evalutaing to `%`.

Having debug setup will also allow you to ensure you have the correct naming conventions for your twig template.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
{% for key, item in content.field_stat_value if key|first != '#' %}
<div class="stat-column">
  {% if content.field_special_character[key] == '%' %}
    {% set attributes = attributes.addClass('percent') %}
  {% elseif content.field_special_character[key] == '$' %}
    {% set attributes = attributes.addClass('dollar') %}
  {% endif %}
    <div {{ attributes.addClass('stat counter').setAttribute('data-count', content.field_stat_value[key]) }}>
      0
    </div>
    <div class="title">{{ content.field_stat_title[key] }}</div>
    <div>{{content.field_special_character[key]}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```